# React:prop eror

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to implement Presentational and Container Components using probs, but I get this error "Cannot read property 'image' of undefined" while trying to access an item passed using props.Below is the code I am using in order of Heirachy.The last class(DishDetail.js) has the problem

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  Main  from './components/MainComponent.js';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Main />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishDetail';


class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
    }; 
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes = {this.state.dishes} 
          onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />

        <DishDetail
         dish = {this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';


class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }


    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
              <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card onClick={(dishId)=>this.props.onClick(dish.id)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
        });

        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

                  {menu}

            </div>

          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

DishDetail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class DishDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    renderComments(comments){
        const comment_layout= comments.map((comment)=>{
            if(comment.comment!=null){
               return(
                   <div>
                                <h4>Comment</h4>
                                {comment.comment}
                                {comment.author}, {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))} 
                    </div>   
               );             

            }else{
                return(
                    <div></div>
                );
            }

        });

        return(comment_layout);

    }


    render() {

        return (

            <div className="row col-sm-12 col-12 m-1 container">
                <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <Card>

                        <CardImg top src={this.props.dish.image} alt={this.props.dish.name}/>
                        <CardBody>
                            <CardTitle>{this.props.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                            <CardText>{this.props.dish.description}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12 m-1">
                        {this.renderComments(this.props.dish.comments)}

                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: On first render your `state.selectedDish` is `null` and so you're passing `null` as `dish` prop. Either set `selectedDish` to a value or render `DishDetail` only if there is something selected. That's possible by adding `{ this.state.selectedDish && <DishDetail dish = {...}/>}`

Comment: @AWolf worked well!